# Lua - Number to string behaviour

Tags: c, lua, tostring

I would like to know how Lua handles the number to string conversions using the `tostring()` function.

It is going to convert to an int (as string) if the number is round (i.e if `number == (int) number`) or is it always going to output a real (as string) like `10.0` ?

I need to mimic the exact behaviour of Lua's `tostring` in C, without using the Lua C API since, in this case, I'm not using a `lua_State`.

Comment: It depends on Lua version.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In Lua 5.2 or earlier, both `tostring(10)` and `tostring(10.0)` result as the string `"10"`.

In Lua 5.3, this has changed:

```
print(tostring(10)) -- "10"
print(tostring(10.0)) -- "10.0"
```

That's because Lua 5.3 introduced the integer subtype. From [Changes in the Language](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#8.1):

> The conversion of a float to a string now adds a `.0` suffix to the result if it looks like an integer. (For instance, the float `2.0` will be printed as `2.0`, not as `2`.) You should always use an explicit format when you need a specific format for numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So it's not as easy as I expected. I'm using 5.3.2 and not planning to use another version.

Answer (score 6):

Lua converts the numbers as is:

```
print(tostring(10)) => "10"
print(tostring(10.0)) => "10.0"
print(tostring(10.1)) => "10.1"
```

If you want to play around with them, there's a small online parser for simple commands like this : http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo
This uses Lua 5.3.1

**edit**
I must support Egor's comment, it's version dependent.
I ran this locally on my system:

```
Lua 5.2.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print(tostring(10))
10
> print(tostring(10.0)) 
10
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this. Isn't there an official documentation about the lua's tostring function ? I've been searching but the information is really sparse and you have to read the whole book everytime you want a piece of info...

Comment: all I could find was http://www.lua.org/pil/2.4.html  and http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_tostring

Comment: Well as I suspected, if number == (int) number, it prints an int. I can't beleive there is no official documentation of these basic functions. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using 5.3.4 and you need a quick hotfix, use math.floor - it casts it to an int-number. This beats @warspyking answer in efficiency, but lacks the coolness that is bunches of code.

```
>tostring(math.floor(54.0))
54
>tostring(54.0)
54.0
>type(math.floor(54.0))
integer
>type(54.0)
number
```

Answer (score 1):

In Lua 5.3, due to the integer type, `tostring` on a float (although it's Numeric value may be equivalent to an integer) will add a `"'.0'` suffix, but that doesn't mean you can't shorten it!

```
local str = tostring(n)
if str:sub(-2) == ".0" then
    str = str:sub(1,-3)
end
```